# Cannot Decode JSON Response Using Swift

Tags: ios, json, api

I am trying to complete a pretty standard thing: decode a JSON response. I can get the data, however decoding does not succeed - worse, there is no error message. Print statement 1 & 2 output with the correct data but I get no output from print statement 3, it outputs print statement 4 instead (e.g. my error message).

I am hoping someone can see my probably obvious error, thanks for any hints that could resolve me issue!

Phil

(Edit) Added JSON Response:

```
[{
    "open": {
        "price": 122.52,
        "time": 1668853732275
    },
    "close": {
        "price": 125.44,
        "time": 1658436480762
    },
    "high": 125.35,
    "low": 123.57,
    "volume": 75244144,
    "symbol": "AAPL"
}]
```

```
struct ResponsePrice: Codable {
    var results: [ResultPrice]
}

struct ResultPrice: Codable {
    var open: ResultPriceTime
    var close: ResultPriceTime
    var high: Double
    var low: Double
    var volume: Double
    var symbol: String
}

struct ResultPriceTime: Codable {
    var price: Double
    var time: Double
}
```

```
///
struct SymbolView: View {
    @State private var results = [ResultPrice]()

    var body: some View {
        List(resultsPrice, id: \.symbol) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.symbol)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(item.symbol)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/ohlc?symbols=aapl&token=Tpk_af03c7f5bac14742a7ce77969a791c66") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    //let stringData = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                    //print(stringData)
                    if let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponsePrice.self, from: data) {
                        // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                        print("Fetched: \(url)")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            // update our UI
                            self.results = decodedResponse.results
                            print("Ticker:\(self.results[0].T)")
                        }
                        
                        // everything is good, so we can exit
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                fatalError("Couldn't parse as :\n\(error)")
            }

            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("4 Decode failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            // step 4
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct SymbolView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SymbolView()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you cannot decode then your model does not fit your JSON, check field by field, or post here JSON itself with all related your models.

Comment: There is no error message because you have explicitly discarded errors with `try?`.  You should use `do/try/catch` and then you can access the error that is caught. However, trying to retrieve and decode json data in your view is the wrong approach. Views are ephemeral and often have a short lifetime. You should have a model object that fetches and exposes the data. The view's job is just to display it.

Comment: Thanks Asperi, I added the JSON response.

Comment: Hi Paulw, thanks for hint,  I moved the model to its own file. New challenge for me now, is how to pass the price data back to the state variable (I get the error: "cannot find self in scope").

Comment: As said, do not write `try?`. Instead: `do { let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder()...  } catch { print("Got error when decoding; \(error)" }`. And tell us what's the output. I can see the first issue about your JSON being an Array at top level, but it should be said in the error and reading it is the first step to debug which would do any developer.

Comment: The fix would be `JSONDecoder().decode(ResponsePrice.self, from: data)` => `let prices = JSONDecoder().decode(ResultPrice.self, from: data)` & `self.resultsPrice = prices`.

Comment: Your structs don’t match the JSON. There is no dictionary with key `results`.

Comment: Thanks for the message, when I update to "try JSONDecoder.decode(...)", I receive a new error: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'ResponsePrice'" (I updated the code above with do/try/catch logic)